# RegEX to extract Variables names, operators, and quoted strings with symbols

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to break a string (from command line argument) into 4 components. (C++ variable name):(python variable)(operator)(value or quoted string)

Example:

```
CVariable_1:PythonVariable.attribute<=2343.23
result=('CVariable_1','PythonVariable.attribute','<=','2343.23')

CVariable_2:PythonVariable2.attribute2.value<="Any string including SYMBOLS~!@#$%^&*\"\'<> and spaces"
result=('CVariable_2','PythonVariable2.attribute2.value','==','Any string including SYMBOLS@#$%\"\'<> and spaces')
```

The closest regex I've come up with is:

```
[^:'"<>=]+|[\.\w]+|[<>!=]+
```

But the string could have any symbols in it.  Quotes would be escaped though.

Comment: Why do you need a regex? Split on the first colon, then the first appearance of `<=` - everything else is the value. Or use the structure that you have - the C and Python variables are going to only be `\w`ord characters: https://regex101.com/r/SZP3Mx/1.

Comment: I had a typo.  All operators are possible so I thought a regex would be easier.

Comment: Then one option would be to enumerate the possible operators (e.g. add `(?P<op>==|<=)` instead of just `<=` into the above example), or you could even use `ast` on the Python part which will parse it properly for you.

Comment: OK, I see.  doing '(^\w+):(\w+(?:\.\w+)+)(==|!=|<=|>=|<|>)(.*)' seems to work.  Except I forgot to mention that ':' is an optional delimiter where if its not given, I'd like the first group to return none

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `([^:]+(?=:))?([^<=!]+)([<>=!]+)(.*$)` will work.

I tried the following code:

```py
import re
import typing

pattern = re.compile(r"([^:]+(?=:))?([^<=!]+)([<>=!]+)(.*$)")
def split_name(name: str) -> typing.Tuple[str, str, str, str]:
    global pattern

    match = re.match(pattern, name)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError("The name is invalid")
    
    cname = match.group(1)
    pyname = match.group(2)
    operator = match.group(3)
    value = match.group(4)

    return cname, pyname, operator, value

test_names = ["PythonVariable1.attribute.value==False",
              "CVariable_2:PythonVariable2.attribute<=2343.23",
              "CVariable_3:PythonVariable3.attribute3.value<=\"Any string including SYMBOLS~!@#$%^&*\\\"\\'<> and spaces\""]

print(list(map(split_name, test_names)))
```

---

If you want to write the allowed operators explicitly, you can change the third group. Note that the order is important in this case (`<=` needs to come before `<`):

```regex
([^:]+(?=:))?([^<=!]+)(<=|>=|!=|==|<|>)(.*$)
```

Comment: Is there a way to make the cname group optional?  For example, if the input is 'PythonVariable==123', I'd like cname=None, pyname='PythonVariable/, operator='==', value='123'

Comment: @eng3 Yes, there is. I changed my code accordingly. The idea is to make the first group optional and use a lookbehind expression to "connect" it to the colon.

Comment: I meant if there was a way to do it in the regex.  I had written a workaround similar to your solution and that works too.